# Centering a div while using particle.js

Tags: html, css, centering, particle.js

I am using particle.js library to use particles as background. I want to center the div "container" but I'm unable to do it using flexbox because canvas is getting inserted when I run the html page.
Please give a solution for this.
Here is the code.

```
<div id="particles-js" style=" height:100vh ">
     <div id="container"> content i want to center </div>
     <canvas> Particle js canvas gets inserted here </canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only two ways I see to fix this are:

1. Set the `position` of the canvas to `absolute` and position it using the properties `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`.
2. Move the canvas to another parent div and not have it be a sibling of `#container`

Answer (score 0):

After some effort I got the solution

```
#particles-js{
    position:relative;
}

#container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    z-index:5;
}
```

Check this page for centering : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/